# Sum of two linear systems on $K3$ surfaces

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a $K3$ surface. Let $|E|$ be a base point free linear system on $X$. If there exists another linear system $|L|$ on $X$ such that $|L|$ is ample (then $|L|$ is base point free), then is it true that the linear system $|L+E|$ is also base point free?

Can anyone point a concrete example (or a brief argument to see this)?

Comment: Given a point $p$ in $X$, by your hypothesis on base-point-freeness, there is an element $L'$ in $|L|$ and an element $E'$ in $|E|$ such that $p$ does not lie in $L'$ or $E'$. Hence $L'+E'$ is an element of $|L+E|$ which does not contain $p$.

Comment: @Kapil, thanks for the answer. This shows that given any point $p \in X$, it can't be a base point of $|L+E|$ and hence $|L+E|$ is base point free. I have one further question: Does there exist any result in the literature which guarantees existence of smooth divisors in $|L+E|$? (I mean smooth divisors inside any base point free linear system on a $K3$ surface?)

Comment: @Sherlock Bertini's theorem.